# Error while opening Excel workbook with Python

Tags: python, xlrd

I can't open .xlsx documents from my iMac while it's not a problem on my macbook pro. Is there an installation I forgot?

This is my code:

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook,cellname

book = open_workbook("/Users/mathias/Dropbox/Python/users.xlsx")
```

And the error:

```
...
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 394, in open_workbook
    f = open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/mathias/Dropbox/Python/users.xlsx'
```

Comment: The obvious answer is that the filename or directory name is wrong.  Are you **SURE** that the filename is correct, including capitalization?

Comment: Actually it was that simple. Thank you!